# Locating town named Porshwel(?) in Lithuania

Tags: historical-gazetteer, lithuania

I have recordings of my grandfather's cousin interviewing his father about life in Lithuania during the late 1800s and early 1900s. Asked where he was born, my great great uncle says,

> "I was born on a farm. Uh, near, between, between, uh, Pumpyan and
>   [unclear, maybe Porshwel]. Between Pumpyan and [unclear, maybe
>   Porshwel]."

I've done research and have located the latitude and longitude of Pumpyan, but I'm having trouble identifying Porshwel. Was there a town in the Lithuanian area with this name? What are its longitude and latitude and how can I find out more about it.

(The spelling 'Porshwel' is a phonetic transcription of what he says during the interview. The sound is sub-par. It's possible I've spelled or heard wrong. I would post a snippet of the recording but I don't think I can do that on this site.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of possibilities very near by Pumpyan. Could "Porshwel" be either "Pushlot" (#1) or "Poshwol" (#2)?

1. There is a town named [Pušalotas](https://www.jewishgen.org/Communities/Community.php?usbgn=-2618249) about 7 km west of Pumpėnai (Pumpyan). Pušalotas has also been called Pushelat (Yiddish), Pushelaty (Russian), Puszolaty (Polish), Puscheloten (German), Pishelot, Pushlat, Puselat, and Pusholaty. The KehilaLinks site has quite a bit of information about Pušalotas, including some old [photos](https://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/pusalotas/photos_past.html). Pušalotas is at [55° 56′ 0″ N, 24° 14′ 40″ E](https://tools.wmflabs.org/geohack/geohack.php?pagename=Pu%C5%A1alotas&params=55_56_00_N_24_14_40_E_type:city(692)_region:LT).
2. There is also a town named [Pasvalys](https://www.jewishgen.org/Communities/community.php?usbgn=-2617762) 15 km north of Pumpėnai. This one is more likely; its alternate names include Posvol (Russian, Yiddish), Poswol (Polish, German), Pasvale (Latvian), Pasvul, Posvul, Pasvalīs, Pasvalio, and Pozwoł. The KehilaLinks site has a page about [Pasvalys](https://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/pasvalys/), including a page listing a few [immigrants to the US](https://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/pasvalys/Poswol%20Pasvalys%20Immigrant%20Data.htm) from Pasvalys. Pasvalys is at [56° 3′ 34″ N, 24° 24′ 13″ E](https://tools.wmflabs.org/geohack/geohack.php?pagename=Pasvalys&params=56_3_34_N_24_24_13_E_region:LT_type:city(8500)).